# Seeing "Cannot modify header information" error when attempting to redirect

Tags: php, email, header

I have a basic PHP `mail()` script which e-mails users the details of a form they've just  submitted.  The PHP inserts all the data into the database fine, but there's a problem when I want to redirect them after the data has finished processing.

I'm currently using:

```
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);

header('Location: '/reservations/?res='.$res.'&id='.$id.'');
```

But it's throwing up this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

I realise you can't send multiple headers, but is there any way of differentiating between the mail and location headers?  I don't want to use JavaScript redirect because it's too slow and lags.  I read somewhere about `ob_start()` but I don't know if that's necessary...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the HTTP header with [`header`](http://php.net/header) requires that it has not been sent yet. And that happens when the first output happened.

So to avoid the HTTP header being sent you need to avoid any output before calling `header` or you need to buffer it so that it doesn’t get sent (see [output control](http://php.net/book.outcontrol), especially [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start)).

The position where the output happened that caused sending the HTTP header is in the error message (“output started at *file*‍:‍*line*”).

Answer (score 4):

mail() doesn't generate any output. You probably have some whitespace at the top of the file before the opening `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "@" symbol before the mail function, it will be solve your problem.

ie.,

```
@mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: /reservations/?res='.$res.'&id='.$id);
```

Comment: This will only suppress any possible error messages. If there's an error with mail (and we don't know if there is), it's better to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: '/reservations/?res='.$res.'&id='.$id.'');
?>
```

Should work just fine. Just make sure you have nothing else happening before this. In other words, do not have a `<body>`, `<title>`, `<head>` or anything above your code.

If you for some reason want to have this make sure your php code still is above all that.

Exampel:

```
<?php
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
header('Location: '/reservations/?res='.$res.'&id='.$id.'');
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Send mail</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi better option is u can use javascript window.location to return the page
like 
echo 'window.location="/reservations/?res=$res&id=$id"'