# Redirect form to thank you page after submission

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I have created a contact form in PHP. The form works fine and sends the message but when I try to redirect users to my thank you page I receive a headers already sent message.

My form starts:

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" class="form-foot" action="/receiving.php" method="post">
```

And the PHP code for receiving.php is:

```
<?php 

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{
$from_add = "mysite@mysite.com"; 

$to_add = "mysite@mysite.com"; 

$subject = "Contact Form";

$message = "
Name:$name \n 
Email: $email \n 
Message: $message \n 

$headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";


if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
{
    Header("Location: /thanks");
} 
}


?>
```

How can I redirect users to www.mysite.com/thanks after successful submission?

Comment: Here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459204/seeing-cannot-modify-header-information-error-when-attempting-to-redirect

Comment: When you are done going through the duplicate you may want to read a bit on the topic of header injection

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure there is NO output before `header` calls. Any echos or any space before `<?php` will break it.
2. `header("location:...")` needs an absolute URI.

   ```
   header("location: http://www.site.tld/thanks");
   ```
3. `header("location: /thanks");` should have an `exit` immediately following.

   ```
   header("location: http://www.site.tld/thanks"); exit;
   ```

Comment: It is not about the putting `exit` after the header, or using absolute URI's I think, it is about output buffering.

Comment: The output buffering issue was only one problem. If I can help with more things, then I am solving the problem and not only the symptoms.

Comment: Hi Joe, I've tried that and I'm still getting the same error:  Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: Then you're not showing us your full code.

Comment: In general, headers (e.g. "Location") should start with a capital, even though they will work when in lower-case.