# Redirect after a contact form submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

Having some trouble with my contact form, when I use the header redirect it is coming up with error.

This is my HTML

```
    <form method="post" action="action.php">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required placeholder="Name" />
      <label for="name">Phone number:</label>
      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required placeholder="Phone" />
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="email@example.com" />
      <label for="message">Message:</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" required></textarea>
      <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
    </form>
```

And now the corresponding action.php file

```
<?php
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $phone=$_POST['phone'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $message=$_POST['message'];

  $to = "xx@hotmail.com";
  $subject = "subject";
  $message = " Name: " . $name . "\r\n email: " . $email . "\r\n phone: " . $phone. "\r\n message: " . $message;


  $from = "noreply@xx.com.au";
  $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 

  if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
       mail($email, "Thanks For for contacting xx - We will be in contact soon", $a_thank_you_message, "From: noreply@xx.com.au" );

   header( 'Location: http://www.xx.com.au' ) ;

?>
```

It displays the following error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at
>          /home/xx/public_html/action.php:3) in /home/xx/public_html/action.php on line 26

Any help would be much appreciated,
Cheers
Peter

Comment: Google your error message.

Comment: It means you printed something earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, a header redirect will fail (ie throw that error message) when the page has output anything before the `header()` call.  In your case, it is possible that you have some whitespace before your opening `<?php` tag in action.php.  Delete anything that is before your opening tag and make sure that there is no output before `header()` (no `echo` or anything like that).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459204/seeing-cannot-modify-header-information-error-when-attempting-to-redirect) for more details.

Comment: You sir are a legend! I cannot believe is was something so simple. and thank you for such a quick reply!